# Python - open two or more windows console windows and write text to them

Tags: python, winapi, pexpect, windows-console

On linux - I can use the PTY and open some xterms... Trying to figure out the equivalent on Windows.

The example is this: Test automation for embedded software devices.

I have a Python Expect Script that talks with several Serial Port devices, the expect script sends a command to (A), waits for results - the standard Python Expect interaction one would find.  At the same time, the Expect script is doing the same with Device (B) and Device (C).

Device examples could be: RaspberryPi, Arduino, etc ... they have a "human like console" where you can enter commands.

What I would like to be able to do, is open 3 "console like windows" one for each device (a/b/c) and use them sort of like a serial console.

The idea & problem is the HUMAN needs to watch & monitor what is going on during the process, what the Python script needs to be able to do is "snoop traffic" and "inject" keys.

To describe it another way - Imagine having 3 to 4 "teraterm" or "hyperterm" or "putty" windows active at the same time - each window is associated with a different device (A, B, C or D).  And there is a PYTHON script that is interacting with these 3 to 4 'teraterm' or 'hyperterm' windows.

Suggestions?

Comment: A Windows process can attach to only one console at a time. It's a private interface to an instance of the console host, which is a conhost.exe process in Windows 7+. You can cycle the connection among multiple consoles, but if the user happens to close a console while you're attached, your process will be unavoidably terminated. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: You could create 3 process via `suprocess.Popen` with `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` passed in `creationflags`. Then for IPC use a `multiprocessing.connection`  `Listener` and `Client` with a named pipe connection.

Comment: *"Suggestions?"* is not a question you should be asking on Stack Overflow. You need to ask a *specific* question, that's answerable. Also, don't ask about your solution. Ask about the problem instead.